# Vim noremap still causes old mappings to be active

Tags: vim, hotkeys, remapping

This is my .vimrc

```
set mouse=a
set ttymouse=xterm2
set number
set smartindent
set tabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
set expandtab
inoremap {      {}<Left>
inoremap {<CR>  {<CR>}<Esc>O
inoremap {{     {
inoremap {}     {}
inoremap (      ()<Left>
inoremap [      []<Left>
noremap ; l 
noremap l k 
noremap k j 
noremap j h 
set nocompatible
filetype plugin on
```

I've tried to remap hjkl to jkl; because that made more sense to me (I wouldn't have to take my hands off the home row to move). But it seems that the old mappings are still there. So now hjkl and jkl; will move the cursor in a direction, creating diagonal cursor movement when trying to go up or down.

What am I doing wrong? noremap should remove the old mappings, correct?

EDIT: I'm an idiot, there were spaces in the vimrc that screwed it up.

Comment: Would you consider writing your answer below as an "answer"?  May have been a simple solution, but I guarantee someone else, someday, will have a similar problem :) After a bit of time, you can actually "accept" the answer.

Comment: Also, it's unrelated to your question...but `set nocompatible` really ought to come before everything else. That option resets a lot of other options.

Answer (score 0):

Trailing spaces at the end of lines that specify new key bindings cause additional space keystrokes to be included as well. This is why OP was getting diagonal cursor movement when they remapped `hjkl` to `jkl;`. This goes for any remapping as well.

For example, if I have the following in my .vimrc file:

```
noremap a ik
```

`a` will be mapped to the keystrokes `ik` in sequence (i.e. pressing <kbd>i</kbd> and then pressing <kbd>k</kbd>).